# Looping through files and extracting value in filename. Script not working

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

Why do I get a "Permission denied" error with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "no argument given"
    exit 1
fi

for i in /sys/class/rc/rc*; do
    if [ -e "$i/device/driver/$1" ]; then
      number=echo $i | sed 's%/sys/class/rc/rc([0-9]+)%$0%'
      echo "found $number"
    fi
done
```

What I would expect to happen is that $number contains the "digit" value of the path /sys/class/rc/rc[0-2], instead, the "echo" command seems to try to cat the file /sys/class/rc/rc[0-2].

In particular, if /sys/class/rc/rc1/device/driver/pwm-ir-transmitter exists, the output of

> lircprobe pwm-ir-transmitter

is:

> /usr/local/sbin/lircprobe: 10: /usr/local/sbin/lircprobe: /sys/class/rc/rc1: Permission denied

(lircprobe is the name of the script, above)

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you sure you hare read permissions on /sys/class/rc/rc1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I see right off:
`number=echo $i | sed 's%/sys/class/rc/rc([0-9]+)%$0%'`
The shell does not know to execute that as a command and store the output in the variable number. Try this instead:
`` number=`echo $i | sed 's%/sys/class/rc/rc([0-9]+)%$0%' ` ``
or
`number=$( echo $i | sed 's%/sys/class/rc/rc([0-9]+)%$0%' )`